# Help- Optical Sensor interfacing with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I am a newbie and I wanted to know if it is safe to connect this NPN output [sensor](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Omron%20PDFs/E3Z.pdf) directly to one of the GPIO pins of the [Sparkfun redboard](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13975). Do I need some extra circuitry or components? Thanks

Comment: top left schematic on page 5 ... safe ........ bottom schematic ... not safe